# Kotlin parse Object array using JSONParser from Gson

Tags: android, kotlin, gson

I have these classes written in kotlin, Location, and the rest is in the Application.kt

```
@RealmClass
open class Location(
    @PrimaryKey
    @SerializedName("id")
    var id: Int = 0,

    @SerializedName("city_name")
    var city_name: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("elevation")
    var elevation: Int = 0,

    @SerializedName("state_code")
    var state_code: String? = null,

    @SerializedName("state_name")
    var state_name: String? = null,

    @SerializedName("country_code")
    var country_code: String? = null,

    @SerializedName("country_name")
    var country_name: String? = null

):RealmObject()
```

and the rest:

```
private fun loadStuff() {
    val inputStream = this.resources.openRawResource(R.raw.city_json)
    val jsonReader = JsonReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"))
    val gson = Gson()
    Realm.getDefaultInstance().executeTransactionAsync(Realm.Transaction { realm ->
        val weatherList = gson.fromJson<List<Location>>(jsonReader , Array<Location>::class.java).toList()
        //realm.insertOrUpdate(location)

        jsonReader.endArray()
        jsonReader.close()
    }, Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess {
        Log.d("TAG", "Success")
    })
}
```

and I keep getting exception:

```
com.example.android.sunshine.data.Location[] cannot be cast to java.lang.Iterable
```

what am I doing wrong ?

the object looks like this:

```
[
  {
     "id":3040051,
     "city_name":"les Escaldes",
     "elevation":0,
     "state_code":"08",
     "state_name":"Parròquia d'Escaldes-Engordany",
     "country_code":"AD",
     "country_name":"Andorra"
  },
  {
     "id":3041563,
     "city_name":"Andorra la Vella",
     "elevation":0,
     "state_code":"07",
     "state_name":"Parròquia d'Andorra la Vella",
     "country_code":"AD",
     "country_name":"Andorra"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
List<Location>
```

Is a List of Location. List implements Iterable.

This:

```
Array<Location>
```

is an Array of Location. Array does not implement Iterable.

The differences are bigger than that, but his is the one your error is for.

Comment: Okay, so I just need to swap Array for a List ? Also. Why is it there the .toList ?

Comment: I would say remove or swap one of those type declarations so that they agree. .toList() is there to make what I assume to be some other collection into a list.

Answer (score 0):

It was enough to swap List with Array and remove .toList() and it worked like magic